# String literal and character concatenation output

Tags: string, output, literals

why is the output of **System.out.println('j' + 'a' + "v" + 'a');** is "**203va** ? why does the last character a converted to its ASCII value here?

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quotes around v, which means it will be treated as a string.